# How can answers for a question be older than the question?

Tags: support, merged-questions

For example [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33054229/accessing-attributes-on-literals-work-on-all-types-but-not-int-why) was asked yesterday but several answers to the question were posted more than 3 years ago.

Comment: I would say SO quality. Ask a question and you get your answer faster than you can type it! (No, the question just got merged: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/33054229/revisions ; with this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10955703/3933332)

Comment: It's called preemptive answering. You haven't head of it yet?

Comment: Seriously, we have dupe for that, haven't we?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Yes, we wrote the dupe already 3 years ago, you know... preventively :)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ... And miss the perfectly good opportunity to merge an answered question with this dupe?

Comment: @PetahChristian Seems I'm just a bit lame today :-P ...